# code multiple comboboxes on excel userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with multiple dependent Comboboxes. I would like to add the following code to 10 of the Comboboxes Change event. The Comboboxes to be coded are Numbered 11 to 20 (Combobox11, Combobox 12, etc) while the dependent Comboboxes are numbered 21 to 30.

I could copy and paste the code 10 times and then find and replace the relevant Combobox Nos.

Is there a way to use a loop through the Combo-Boxes to achieve this?
Any assistance would be most grateful.

```
Private Sub ComboBox11_Change()

Dim index As Integer
index = ComboBox11.ListIndex
ComboBox21.Clear

Select Case index
    Case Is = 0
        With ComboBox21
            .RowSource = Range("SubCat1").Address(external:=True)
        End With

    Case Is = 1
        With ComboBox21
            .RowSource = Range("SubCat6").Address(external:=True)
        End With

    Case Is = 2
        With ComboBox21
            .RowSource = Range("SubCat7").Address(external:=True)
        End With

    Case Is = 3
        With ComboBox21
            .RowSource = Range("SubCat8").Address(external:=True)
        End With

    Case Is = 4
        With ComboBox21
            .RowSource = Range("SubCat9").Address(external:=True)
        End With

    'and several more case options

End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **Class** Module, and a `User_Init` Sub to set each ComboBox control in the user form to this class.

In my code I used **Main_Form** as the name of the User_Form, modify the code according to your User_Form Name.

Add a Calls Module, and add this code below in Class 1:

```
Public WithEvents ComboBoxEvents As MSForms.ComboBox

 ' anytime a Change event occurs to any ComboBox, the Sub is triggered
Private Sub ComboBoxEvents_Change()

Dim ComboBox_Index As String
Dim index As Integer

    With ComboBoxEvents
        ' read the index of the ComboBox, as long as the names remain ComboBox1, ComboBox2, ComboBox3, etc...
        ComboBox_Index = Mid(.Name, 9)

        ' run this code if it's ComboBox 11 to 20
        If ComboBox_Index >= 11 And ComboBox_Index <= 20 Then
            index = .ListIndex

            Select Case index
                Case Is = 0
                    With Main_Form.Controls("ComboBox" & ComboBox_Index + 10)
                        .RowSource = Range("SubCat1").Address(external:=True)
                    End With

                Case Is = 1
                    With Main_Form.Controls("ComboBox" & ComboBox_Index + 10)
                        .RowSource = Range("SubCat6").Address(external:=True)
                    End With

                Case Is = 2
                    With Main_Form.Controls("ComboBox" & ComboBox_Index + 10)
                        .RowSource = Range("SubCat7").Address(external:=True)
                    End With

                Case Is = 3
                    With Main_Form.Controls("ComboBox" & ComboBox_Index + 10)
                        .RowSource = Range("SubCat8").Address(external:=True)
                    End With

                Case Is = 4
                    With Main_Form.Controls("ComboBox" & ComboBox_Index + 10)
                        .RowSource = Range("SubCat9").Address(external:=True)
                    End With

                'and several more case options

            End Select                
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

The code below goes in your **User_Form_Init** (in my code the name of the User_Form is *Main-Form*) :

```
Option Explicit

Dim ComboBoxes() As New Class1

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ComboBoxCounter As Integer, Obj As Control

    For Each Obj In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf Obj Is MSForms.ComboBox Then
            ComboBoxCounter = ComboBoxCounter + 1
            ReDim Preserve ComboBoxes(1 To ComboBoxCounter)
            Set ComboBoxes(ComboBoxCounter).ComboBoxEvents = Obj
        End If
    Next Obj

    Set Obj = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: When you say the code goes into your User_Form_Init do you mean the UserForm_Initialize procedure. I put the code there but there were no entries in the comboboxes when I loaded the userform.

Comment: @willi you need to add you original code of `UserForm_Initialize` to my code above, after the line `Set Obj = Nothing`, am I clear ?

Comment: I added the code to the UserForm_ initialize procedure but it does not accept the Option Explicit or the Dim statement "ComboBoxCounter As Integer, Obj As Control" being placed above the sub name. What am I missing? I will be out of the office for a few days.

Comment: @willi do you have the Class 1 module ready with the code before ?

Comment: Shai, I have renames the userform to Main_Form, inserted a class module and copied your code into it. I then went to the Main_Form initialize procedure and copied the relevant cod into it. I then created a sub to load & Show Main_Form. But when I click on checkboxes 21to 30 they are empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: @willi you mean Combo-Box, right ? check your post. the code refers ComboBox objects, and not checkboxes like you just mentioned

Comment: Shai, Everything is working fine, I found a typing error in a declaration. Thank you for the solution and your continued interest. willi

Answer (score 0):

the way is using Class

add a Class module and name it after "CmbBox" (you can choose whatever name but be consistent with it)

add the following code into the class code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents Cmb As MSForms.ComboBox

Private Sub Cmb_Change()
    Dim index As Long

    With Cmb
        index = .ListIndex
        With .Parent.Controls("ComboBox" & Mid(.Name, 9) + 10)
            .Clear
            Select Case index
                Case 0
                    .RowSource = Range("SubCat1").Address(external:=True)
                Case 1 To 4
                    .RowSource = Range("SubCat" & index + 5).Address(external:=True)
            End Select
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Then switch to your userfom code pane and add this code:

```
Dim Cmbs(1 To 10) As New CmbBox '<--| this must be at the very top of your userform code pane

Sub Userform_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long

    With Me.Controls
        For i = 11 To 20
            Set Cmbs(i - 10).Cmb = .Item("ComboBox" & i)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

and that's it

Comment: @willi: did you try this solution? It's quite short -> maintanable

Comment: @willi: it'd be nice of you to give feedbacks to people trying and help you